# Не могу установить библиотеку Python – pyA20

Tags: python, python-3.x, gpio

Есть мини-ПК Orange PI PC. Задался вопросом использования GPIO, а установить библиотеку не получается.

Пробовал версию ниже устанавливать, результат одинаков. Растолкуйте на пальцах пожалуйста, что не так?

Библиотеку `setuptools` используемую `pyA20` я установил без проблем.
На ПК стоит Python 2.7 и 3.7. Для установки библиотек использовал команду `sudo pip3 install pyA20`.

Comment: Что именно не получается? Какие ошибки?

Comment: 1 минуту скрины выложу нормальные

Comment: Он пытался подгрузить `pyhton.h`, но не смог, из за этого ошибка компиляции (строка `compilation terminated` в конце ошибки)

Comment: Попробуйте варианты [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53204916)

Comment: Решением проблемы стала команда """sudo apt-get install python3-dev""".Спасибо за помощь

Comment: Для работы с GPIO используйте нормальные, официальные средства ядра, а именно библиотеку `libgpiod`.

Answer (score 0):

Решением проблемы стала команда """sudo apt-get install python3-dev"""